# valores máximos

Tags: r, data.frame

como eu faço para selecionar os 5 maiores valores (km nesse exemplo) em um conjunto de dados? Eu só conheço a função which() e max(), mas elas dão apenas o maior de todos, não os 5 maiores por exemplo.

```
dados <- data.frame(nome = letters[1:11],
                    km = c(10,220,320,310,506,490,120,15,16,67,506))


max(dados$km)
which(dados$km == max(dados$km))
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma opção seria:

```
library(dplyr)

arrange(dados, desc(km))[1:5]
```

Uma segunda opção seria:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dados)
dados[order(km, decreasing = T)][1:5,]
```

Ambas geram a mesma solução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só detalhismo com a sintaxe do data.table: não precisa das vírgulas ao final: `dados[order(km, decreasing = TRUE)][1:5]` funciona igual.

Comment: Ótimo! Vou editar!

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução utilizando *dplyr* e mantendo o *data.frame*.

```
library(dplyr)
     dados %>% 
    # Ordenando os valores
      arrange(-km) %>% 
    # Selecionando os 5 maiores
      slice(1:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Mesmo princípio da [solução de Josiane Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/523390/117168) (ordenar os dados e selecionar os 5 primeiros - ou últimos, dependendo da ordenação), mas com R base:

```
tail(sort(dados$km), 5)
# ou
head(sort(dados$km, decreasing = TRUE), 5)
# ou
sort(dados$km, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]
```

Se quiser os maiores valores sem repetição, pode usar `unique`.

```
tail(unique(sort(dados$km)), 5)
#> [1] 220 310 320 490 506
```